# How To Pass File as a Parameter to POST REST service

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have been trying to upload a multipart file in my Java Spring MVC Web Application through a POST REST service method. I am using JerseyRestClient. I have the controller method consists of the file which I am trying to upload using a Web Service.

I have the following REST service method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap model)
     {

         // codes

        }
```

Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String uploadProfileImage(@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile fileUpload, Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 {

    WebResource webResource = client.resource(serviceRestDomainName + "/upload");
         ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
                .queryParam("file", file)
                .queryParam("userId", String.valueOf(userId))
                .queryParam("siteId", String.valueOf(site.getSiteId()))
                .post(ClientResponse.class);
         returnString = responseMsg.getEntity(String.class);
 }
```

[image: Passing file as a parameter using Postman rest client]
 So i need to know how we can pass file as the parameter for the POST REST service.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="268435456"/>
 </bean>
```

also try adding headers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-image", headers=("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST)
```